# Can I dynamically switch functions inside of a function in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

In Python 3.x is it possible to dynamically choose a function inside of a function or class?
For example in the function below, instead of relying on conditional statements could just enter the method that I would like to use?

```
def npMethodChooser(n,m,method):
    if method == "mean":
        return np.random.rand(n,m).mean(axis=1)
    if method == "std":
        return np.random.rand(n,m).std(axis=1)
```

Comment: well, `eval` would be an option.. Not sure if you want to go down that way though

Comment: Functions are first class objects, so absolutely. `def f(func, x): return func(x)` works as expected. For instance, `f(sum, [1,2,3]) == 6`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamic attribute lookup may be done by using `getattr` function.

```
def npMethodChooser(n, m, method):
    return getattr(np.random.rand(n,m), method)(axis=1)
```

Comment: Way messier than just passing the method directly

Comment: @BallpointBen I'm curious to see how you would do it in this case. The method to be called is part of the object that is dynamically created in the function according to its parameters.

Comment: @VincentSavard See my comment on jsbueno's answer

Comment: @BallpointBen So you argue that `array_like.mean(axis=1)` is a synonym to `np.mean(array_like, axis=1)`? If so, sure, you may pass `np.mean` as an argument. In a general case, OP asks about attribute lookup on instance which is unavailable in caller scope. In that case problem statement simply differs from yours.

Comment: @BryanOakley Good point, although since the function can only handle one type per method (i.e., 'mean' will never be called on anything but an `nparray`) I still think passing the class' method as a parameter is better.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski In general you're right, but OP seems to know what types he'll be dealing with so it shouldn't be a problem. In any case, the function can only handle one type per method.

Answer (score 1):

yes. You can do that.

Just accept the method as a parameter

```
def npMethodChooser(n,m,method):
    result = method(...)
    ...
```

There is usually no need for `getattr` if your caller function has a reference to te function that should be used on the callee: functions are a first class object in Python, and they behave like any other object - 
If a variable that references a function is used with a follwing parenthesis pair and argument list, it is called. (Like any other callable object).

In this specific case, the caller function does not yet have a reference to the final method to be called - it knows the method name - 
In this case you can pass the desired method name as a string, and retrio eve it from your object using `getattr` before calling it:

```
def npMethodChooser(n,m,method):
   obj = np.random.rand(n,m)
   result = getattr(obj, method)(axis = 1)
   return result
```

Comment: Note that in order to pass an object's methods, you reference the class, so you would call the function like `npMethodChooser(n, m, np.nparray.mean)` and inside the function, call the method statically as `method(np.random.rand(n,m))`

Comment: this solution won't work as written, because the method the OP wants to use is an attribute of an object created based on the parameters being passed in. In general,  yes, you can pass methods around. In this case the OP needs to create an object and then call a method on that object. You can't pass in the method unless you create the object first. If you create the object first (in this specific case) there's no point in having the function.

Comment: This could work if you passed `method` as a lambda and relied on lazy evaluation

Comment: @brianpck: sure, several solutions other than this one could work. _this_ solution won't work without details that are not included in the answer.

Comment: yes - but indeed - this explains how Python works  - but as it is now, it does not address the specificity of the question. I will leave it as is - the `getattr` answer is the correct one for this question - but this is the "generic" one that mgith help one searching around and getting to this question. (just fixed the answer, anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

```
def run_my_function(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This function accepts a function `func`, any number of inputs which it stores in a list `args` and any number of keyword arguments, which it store in a dictionary `kwargs`.  It then passes those inputs to the function `func` and returns that functions return value.

```
run_my_function(mean, axis=1)
```

Comment: What do you gain by doing this? You pass a function and its arguments to a function so it can be called. You just added a level of indirection to a function call. See [Inner-platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect)

Comment: You forget the function that will get the first one as  a parameter is not a one-liner-  the other funciton willbe called inside a more complex context.

Comment: this is problematic _in the specific case in the question_, because the method is an attribute of an object created inside the method.